# Non-total functions are treated as constants at the type level?

Tags: typechecking, idris

In *Type-Driven Development with Idris*, ch 6, he says

> - Type-level functions exist at *compile time only* ...
> - Only functions that are total will be evaluated at the type level. A function that isn't total may not terminate, or may not cover all possible inputs. Therefore, to ensure that type-checking itself terminates, functions that are not total are treated as *constants* at the type level, and don't evaluate further.

I'm having difficulty understanding what the second bullet point means.

- How could the type checker claim the code type checks if there's a function that isn't total in its signature? Wouldn't there by definition be some inputs for which the type isn't defined?
- When he says constant, does he mean in the same sense as in [the docs](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html#types-and-functions), like

  ```
  one: Nat
  one = 1
  ```

  is a constant? If so, how could that enable the type checker to complete its job?
- If a type-level function exists at compile time only, does it ever get evaluated if it's not total? If not, what purpose does it serve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial type-level functions are treated as constants in the Skolem sense: invocations of a partial function `f` remain `f` with no further meaning.

Let's see an example. Here `f` is a partial predecessor function:

```
f : Nat -> Nat
f (S x) = x
```

If we then try to use it in a type, it will not reduce, even though `f 3` would reduce to `2`:

```
bad : f 3 = 2
bad = Refl
```

> When checking right hand side of bad with expected type
>           `f 3 = 2`
>
> Type mismatch between
>           `2 = 2` (Type of `Refl`)
>   and
>           `f 3 = 2` (Expected type)

So `f` is an atomic constant here, standing only for itself. Of course, because it *does* stand for itself, the following still typechecks:

```
good : f 3 = f 3
good = Refl
```